# special characters missing

Tags: php, jquery

I have a list of camera names in a html table.  You can hit an edit button to edit the camera name if you wish.

This opens up a form (plus many other options) with the camera name now editable.

```
var edit = function(t, to, cameratype, cameraname, ...)
{
   var mydiv = js("#editform");

   if (mydiv.find("form").length) {
      mydiv.show();
   } else {
    // fields
    var $myform = js("<form id='EditCameraForm' name='' method='post' action='" + to + "'></form>");
    var $myfieldset = js("<fieldset><legend>Edit camera settings</legend></fieldset>");
    var $myinput = js("<input type='hidden' name='camera_type' value='" + cameratype + "' />");
    var $mylabel = js("<label for='CameraName'>Camera name:&nbsp;</label>");
    var $myinput2 = js("<input id='CameraName' name='camera_name' size='25' value='" + cameraname + "'  />");

    $myform.append($myinput, $mylabel, $myinput2, ...);
}
```

My problem is passing in cameraname.  I allow special characters.  So you can call the camera `Joe's camera`.

When I hit the edit button the camera name shows up as just `Joe`.

This has to do with my validation function in php when the camera name is first created...I believe:

```
function check_input($data)
{
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
            $data = htmlentities($data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

            return $data;
 }
```

cameraname is passed in via the button click:

```
<button id="editbutton" onClick='edit(this, "<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>", "<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_type"]; ?>", "<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"]; ?>", ...)'>Edit</button>
```

If you view the page source of this it will show: `Joe&#039;s camera`.  So I thought maybe I have to decode this in the JS code with decodeURIComponent(cameraname) but that doesn't work.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but... throw away the validation function, it will break your data but not provide sufficient protection against SQL injection.

Comment: Throw away? Isn't this common technique to prevent XSS (with @JMack fixes), then use mysql functions for SQL such as mysql_real_escape_string?

Comment: none of the calls inside the function seem useful - to the contrary, the `stripslashes()` call may even break data. `htmlspecialchars()` is the only thing necessary to prevent XSS (no need to convert all entities), and it's enough to apply it when outputting the data, and as you say `mysql_real_escape_string()` if using the data in a `mysql_query()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of building your input boxes like you are, trying using a bit more Jquery.

```
var $myinput = js('<input/>').attr('type','hidden').attr('name','camera_type').val(cameratype);
```

Your problem is most likely you are creating a double quote issue in the `value='" + cameratype + "'` section.

Comment: I have one other place I need to update but I'm not sure how to rewrite: `window.open("file.php?user="+'<?php echo $id_hash; ?>'+"&camera="+camerahash+"&name="+cameraname+"&quality="+cameraflashquality+"&motion="+cameramotion, "Monitor");`. Anything you can suggest?

Answer (score 1):

I see a few things wrong with this code, but lets start with your check_input() function since you think it is suspect.

You should only [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) if you know that magic quotes is on. You are doing an [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) from UTF-8 to UTF-8? Is there a reason for that? [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) works, but I think you want [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

```
function check_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? stripslashes($data) : $data;
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

    return $data;
}
```

TomPepernic said:

> Not sure I understand. I'm sanitizing any user input with check_input such as: $camera_name = check_input($_POST['camera_name']);, then use mysql_real_escape_string before it gets inserted in the DB. This is wrong? – Tom Pepernic 2 hours ago

@TomPepernic As with many questions, it is difficult to give a definitive "right" or "wrong" answer without knowing the full scope of the program. From experience, I can tell you that, while often considered acceptable in many cases, it is rarely the optimal solution.

Making the assumption that the program is "safe" from malicious data based on a single sanitation in the beginning is a flawed model. Because it is rarely possible to know every single possible data outlet, you will not be able to sanitize with a single method to be effective with all of them. At the beginning of the program you are sanitizing for HTML, but that's it. Later on in your program you must escape for SQL, because the sanitization was ineffective. What if later on down the road you decided to store in a different database type that was not SQL? You would again have to sanitize for that particular database. A better method is to assume that the data is tainted at every single level, then sanitize as necessary right before it reaches its outlet.

Another reason is because you are sanitizing for HTML while in the PHP portion of your program. At this stage, it is nearly impossible for malicious data to harm your PHP. Because your PHP code and your HTML code should be separate, you are sanitizing for the wrong language. The sanitization for HTML should come in the "view" portion of your program (assuming you are using an MVC approach).

The final reason that I'll bore you with, is that you are changing your data before you have processed it. Generally, it is a good idea to work with the original data, and store the original data. After you have changed the data, it is more difficult, or impossible, to recover it if you need it later. I learned this the hard way many years ago. I developed a small forum application that used proprietary BBcode like syntax to add text formatting, images, and links. I sanitized and processed my data before storing it, figuring I would never need the original again. later on down the line, I discovered that there was a problem with the syntax, in that it needed to be changed because it was causing some posts to display improperly. I was able to make a correction in my code, which would work properly for all future posts. Unfortunately, all the previous posts that had been affected by the problem could not be fixed, because I had stored them in their broken processed form. If I had stored the originals, I would be able to reprocess them, and none of the data would have been lost.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I should pay more attention. I do swear I had htmlspecialchars, but cut and paste the wrong code.  The rest I have no excuse ;)

Comment: @TomPepernic I noticed is that your function is named "check_input()", but it doesn't actually do that. This function is doing formatting. I would suggest you name it "sanitize_input()", "clean_input()", or something similar.

Comment: @TomPepernic It also appears that you are using htmlspecialchars() in a function to clean your input before processing. This is a common pitfall inexperienced users make with PHP. You do not want to attempt to sanitize your input at the beginning, because you are changing the data you need to work with, and it may not protect you properly here anyway. You want to take the raw data, and process it as you need. Use htmlspecialchars() on it before it is printed back to the page, and use mysql_real_escape_string() before it is inserted into a database.

Comment: Not sure I understand. I'm sanitizing any user input with check_input such as: `$camera_name = check_input($_POST['camera_name']);`, then use mysql_real_escape_string before it gets inserted in the DB.  This is wrong?

Comment: I've added my explanation to the bottom of the answer, because it was too long to fit here. I hope it helps.